# App script form submits to an unknown address after submit

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I wanted to created a simple login form. But whenever the form is submitted, it goes to an address of `https://n-hb3iawsdao7vaebunzezdpvnz2lfhrti7vfmd3a-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel?` with an error of

> Uncaught NetworkError: Connection failure due to HTTP 0

Everything works if I don't enclose it in a form tag but I need to because of the required attribute for the input tags.

Code.GS:

```
function checkLogin(username, password) {
var url = '';

var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
var webAppSheet = ss.getSheetByName("users");
var getLastRow =  webAppSheet.getLastRow();
var found_record = '';
for(var i = 1; i <= getLastRow; i++)
{
  if(webAppSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue() == username && 
  webAppSheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue() == password)
{
  found_record = 'TRUE';
}    
}
if(found_record == '')
{
found_record = 'FALSE'; 
}

return found_record;

}
```

JavaScript:

```
     function loginUser() {

   var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
   var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
   
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(output) 
     {
      if(output == 'TRUE')
      {
       // console.log("Success");
      }
      else if(output == 'FALSE')
      {
       // console.log("Denied");
      }).checkLogin(username, password);
     }
```

HTML:

```html
    <div class="limiter">
     <div class="container-login100" style="background-color: slategrey;">
       <div class="wrap-login100">
         <form onsubmit="loginUser()">

                <span class="login100-form-logo">
                    <img src="sample.png" border="0">
                </span>

                <span class="login100-form-title p-b-34 p-t-27">
                    Intranet
                </span>

                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Enter username">
                    <!-- <input class="input100" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"> -->
        <input class="input100" type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username" required>
                    <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf207;"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter password">
                    <!-- <input class="input100" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password"> -->
        <input class="input100" type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                    <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf191;"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                    <button type="submit" class="login100-form-btn">
                        Login
                    </button>
                </div>

         </form>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your script, `loginUser()` is required to be modified. Because, `}` is required to be added. So, when your script is run by clicking the button of "Login", an error occurs beccause `loginUser()` has an issue. So, I'm worried that your showing script might be different from your tested script that occurred the error of `Uncaught NetworkError: Connection failure due to HTTP 0`.
- In this modification, in order to correctly run the script of `withSuccessHandler`, `<form onsubmit="loginUser()">` is modified to `<form onsubmit="loginUser(); return false;">`.
- In your script, I thought that the process cost of `checkLogin` might be able to be reduced.

When these points are reflected in your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

##### Google Apps Script side:

```js
function checkLogin(username, password) {
  var url = '';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var webAppSheet = ss.getSheetByName("users");
  var find = webAppSheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().find(([, b, , d]) => b == username && d == password);
  return find ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
}
```

##### Javascript side:

```js
function loginUser() {
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (output) {
    if (output == 'TRUE') {
      console.log("Success");
    } else if (output == 'FALSE') {
      console.log("Denied");
    }
  }).checkLogin(username, password);
}
```

##### HTML side:

```html
<div class="limiter">
  <div class="container-login100" style="background-color: slategrey;">
    <div class="wrap-login100">
      <form onsubmit="loginUser(); return false;"> <!-- Modified -->

        <span class="login100-form-logo">
          <img src="sample.png" border="0">
        </span>

        <span class="login100-form-title p-b-34 p-t-27">
          Intranet
        </span>

        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter username">
          <!-- <input class="input100" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"> -->
          <input class="input100" type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username" required>
          <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf207;"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter password">
          <!-- <input class="input100" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password"> -->
          <input class="input100" type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
          <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf191;"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
          <button type="submit" class="login100-form-btn">
            Login
          </button>
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that the files of Javascript, HTML and Google Apps Script are put in the same Google Apps Script project. Please be careful about this.
- If you are using Web Apps, when you modified the script, please reflect the latest script to the Web Apps. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Thank you very much @Tanaike! It worked for me and I also appreciate the shorter approach for function checkLogin();

Comment: @Potatou_  Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.